# How to calculate the sum of number array elements from multiple database rows using php?

Tags: php

I need to count the number of elements that exist in the column of a MySQL database row for multiple rows and them add them all together. This is the code I used to count the number of array elements (which are numbers separated by commas):

```
$result = substr_count($count_fetch['micro_analysis'], ",") + 1;
```

But now I need to do this for each row, which could vary depending on the query. I need to add the `$result` of each row together to get a final sum of all the rows. I used the following code but I get the incorrect value, can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id = $order_id";

      $count_query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $count_fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count_query);

      foreach ($count_fetch as $row) {
         $result = substr_count($count_fetch['micro_analysis'], ",") + 1;
         $end_result += $result;

      }

      echo $end_result;
```

Comment: Can you not use MySQL COUNT() or SUM() functions to do the math for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just fetching 1 row and then trying to count over that row, instead you need to loop over the rows and add the fields in that...

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id = $order_id";

  $end_result = 0;
  $count_query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count_query)) {
     $end_result += substr_count($row['micro_analysis'], ",") + 1;
  }

  echo $end_result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id = $order_id";

      $count_query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $count_fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count_query);
      $end_result=0;//initialize variable to 0
      foreach ($count_fetch as $k => $row) {
         if($k == 'micro_analysis'){
           $result = substr_count($row, ",") + 1; //change over here
           $end_result += $result;
         }
      }

      echo $end_result;
```

Comment: I get an error ` Illegal string offset 'micro_analysis'`

Comment: before `foreach`

Comment: add the following code:  `echo "<pre>"; print_r($count_fetch);die();`

Comment: `Array
(
    [sample_id] => 16
    [env_sam_id] => 181207-9-1
    [order_id] => 21
    [c_sam_id] => Test
    [sample_group] => water
    [sample_type] => Test
    [sample_condition] => Test
    [sample_temp] => Test
    [storage_location] => 1
    [s_status] => Analysis Pending
    [s_time1] => 17:36:11
    [s_date1] => 2018-12-07
    [micro_analysis] => 1,2,3
    [chem_analysis] => 1,2
)`

Comment: For some reason it provides the incorrect answer. The answer that @Nigel Ren gave worked for me. Thank you anyways!

Comment: Yes I did indeed.